# Passing an element into a function on load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add an event listener to a dynamically created object with a class of container. There will be multiple containers on a page and I don’t want to call a function to re add the event listeners to every “container” each time one is created and added to the DOM.

I was hoping for a some way to self reference an element, this way I don’t have to use `getElementsByClassName` and `forEach` to add the events, but I can’t get the formatting correct.

I’m hoping for something like:

```html
<div class=“container” onload=addEvents(this)>Some Text</div>
```

Then the JavaScript would be something like

```js
function addEvents(container) {
    container.addEventListener(‘click’, someFunction);
}
```

Then hopefully, this way it will only add events when new elements are created and loaded in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `onload` is only valid on the body element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with a "delegated" event attachment:

```js
// delegated event attachment:
document.querySelector("body").onclick=ev=>{
  ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON" && document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",'<div class="container">A new clickable div! <button>another one</button></div>');
  ev.target.classList.contains("container") && console.log("container was clicked!");
}
```

```css
.container {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div>Something</div>
<div class"abc">else</div>
<div class="container">This one is clickable</div>
<div class="def">This one is not</div>
<div class="container">But this one is clickable again</div>
<div class="container">and so is this</div>
<button>add further clickable containers</button>
```

This way you define the event attachment on the parental level and every new child element will automatically be clickable - following the selection rules in the actual event handler (note the condition: `ev.target.classList.contains("container")`!).

Comment: Yes, you can do all sorts of things in your delegated event handler! I moved the button click handler into it. Try it out.  ;-)